# Color combination suggestions for medium contrast background

Tags: color, contrast

I am developing UI for iPhone App, and in the navigation bar I used this grey color. My requriment is to use font colors which catch the eye. I tried blue but on iPhone the theme is transparent, so the text doesn't get highlighted enough.

What colors can I use in combination with a medium contrast grey? My background color is Red :90 Green :90 Blue :90

Here's my background. This light color is final from the client.

[image]

Comment: Color isn't the issue here as much as contrast is. If you're using a medium gray background, your foreground color needs to be either very bright, or very dark. Try a much brighter, or much darker blue.

Comment: What about bright orange  :D ? Usually when you choose R G B color for background then 255- R 255-G 255-B is suitable. I mean complement color for foreground.

Comment: Use this site http://www.colourlovers.com/palettes

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear what you are asking. However, it sounds like you're having implementation problems more than color issues. I suggest you detail the implementation issue and post this over on StackOverflow.

Comment: You simply need to ensure you've got a high contrast ratio: http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#%23eeeeee-on-%23888

Comment: can any one gives me rgb which are suit this background

Answer (score 3):

Summing up the information on the comments, the problem you are having is that your background doesn't allow for much contrast, because it's neither too dark nor too light.

> **Contrast** is the difference in visual properties that makes an object (or its
>   representation in an image) distinguishable from other objects and the
>   background. [(Source)](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/09/fully-understanding-contrast-in-design/)

Ideally, you should work with backgrounds that allow for more contrast (dark grey - white text, white - dark text). Contrast is essential for readability.

[This tool](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#%23eeeeee-on-%23888) can help you test your colors so you have a good contrast. For your particular color, since it falls right in the middle (it's not too dark or too light), [white](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#%23fff-on-%23747474) or [black](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#%23000-on-%23747474) are the best contrast options (4.7 and 4.5 respectively).

We can't really suggest colors as it would depend on the taste of your client alone. Give that tool a try, prepare some samples and pick one that is both aesthetically pleasing and allows for the text to be highlighted.

Comment: can you gives me rgb which are suit this background?

Comment: You will have to try yourself. It's impossible to tell what your client wants. The tools we mentioned should be all you need to start testing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use this font color: R: 91 , G: 203, B: 245
See screenshot below.[image]

Comment: This one i tried but it now looks good...